# Using random number generate to display images from an arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist, random, android-image

Brief Description: The application will display random images to the user based off the words from the word bank file and the user will have to identify the name of the image, (single word). The user can either "pass" by clicking the pass button or identify the image and then the "next" button will pop up directing them to the next image.

Problem: 
The application keep crashing right before the new next button appears with different images when I attempt to press the next button.

I think that it has something to do with the random number generator or an issue with the if statements i placed.

I am getting no error message. I am not sure what is causing the issue. When I do run the apk file, when it crash it says "unfortunately, pic has stopped"
"pic" is the app name.

**EDIT:** 
When i ran the app through the emulator I got an runtime error message, shown below

The next button is clicked and changes to the next image which is randomizes by the code:

```
        randomNum = (random.nextInt(UnSpokenList.size()) + 1);
```

the first element, contains "Word Bank:" which is not an image, it just the name of the list of word, so I did random.nextInt(maxsize)+1 , which I assume avoids 0, the first element, but when it comes down to the arraylist have the size of 2

(it crashes right before this part, but it does crashes when this next button is click as well.)
In the `onActivityResult` function when it size 2 or less then 2, it will stop showing this next button and show a different next button which call the function onlastPair, which produce images based off the last element of the arraylist.

**Main Code:**
I took some code off functions that aren't related to the issue hopefully it will be easier to find the main problem.

```
    public class Main extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private static final int VR_Request = 100;

    Button restart;
    Button mainMenu;
    Button pass;
    Button next;
    Button last2image;

    TextView speechInput;
    TextView matchOrNot;
    TextView passTitle;
    TextView counterDisplay;

    String[] wordBank;
    ArrayList<String> wordBANK;

    Spinner wordList;
    Spinner SpokenWords;

    ArrayList<String> UnSpokenList;
    ArrayList<String> SpokenList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> wordList_adapter;
    ArrayAdapter<String> SpokenList_adapter;

    ImageButton speechBtn;

    ImageView image;
    Resources res;
    int resID;

    Random random;
    int randomNum;

    int previous;
    int passCounter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pictionary);

        speechInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.english_word1);
        matchOrNot = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.matchOrNot1);
        passTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.passedTitle);
        counterDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.passCounterText);

        wordBank = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Words);

        speechBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mic_pic_button1);

        wordBANK = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(wordBank));
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        res = getResources();

        restart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.restartButton1);
        mainMenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mainMenubutton1);
        pass = (Button) findViewById(R.id.passButton);
        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
        last2image = (Button) findViewById(R.id.last2);

        pass.setClickable(true);

        wordList = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.wordsList1);
        SpokenWords = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spokenWords1);

        UnSpokenList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(wordBank));
        SpokenList = new ArrayList<String>(wordBank.length+1);

        UnSpokenList.add(0, "Word Bank:");
        SpokenList.add(0,"Spoken Words:");
        wordList_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, UnSpokenList);
        wordList_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        wordList.setAdapter(wordList_adapter);
        SpokenList_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, SpokenList);
        SpokenList_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        SpokenWords.setAdapter(SpokenList_adapter);

        random = new Random();
        randomNum = random.nextInt(UnSpokenList.size()-1);
        resID = res.getIdentifier(UnSpokenList.get(randomNum), "drawable", getApplication().getPackageName());
        image.setImageResource(resID);

        pass.setClickable(true);
        pass.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        next.setClickable(false);
        next.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        speechBtn.setClickable(true);
        last2image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        last2image.setClickable(false);
        passCounter = 0;

        restart.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mainMenu.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        passTitle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        counterDisplay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }



    public void onMicButton(View view) {

    }

    /**
     * When the next button is pressed, this function handles the next random image to be displayed
     * @param view
     */
    public void onNext(View view){
        if(view.getId() == R.id.nextButton){
            speechInput.setText("");
            matchOrNot.setText("");

            randomNum = (random.nextInt(UnSpokenList.size()) + 1);

            resID = res.getIdentifier(UnSpokenList.get(randomNum), "drawable", getApplication().getPackageName());
            image.setImageResource(resID);

            next.setClickable(false);
            next.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            pass.setClickable(true);
            pass.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            speechBtn.setClickable(true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This function occurs when the user plays all the way to last 2 image left in game
     */
    public void onlastPair(View view){
        if(view.getId() == R.id.last2){
            if(!UnSpokenList.get(UnSpokenList.size()).contains("Word Bank:")) {
                resID = res.getIdentifier(UnSpokenList.get(UnSpokenList.size()), "drawable", getApplication().getPackageName());
                image.setImageResource(resID);

                speechBtn.setClickable(true);
                pass.setClickable(false);
                pass.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }else {
                onGameOver();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onGameOver(){

    }

    /**
     * when the user clicks the passed button this function is called.
     * It takes the previous image and make sure it does not pop-up again for the next image and then reproduce a different image
     * @param view
     */
    public void onPass(View view){

    }

    public void onResetPic(View view){

    }

    public void reset(){

    }


    public void MainMenu(View view){
    }

    /**
     * shows speech input dialog
     */
    public void promptSpeechInput() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Say a Word from our word bank!");

        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, VR_Request);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
            Toast.makeText(Pictionary.this, "Oops, your device doesn't support speech recognition,", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * detects and recieve speech input
     * @param requestCode
     * @param resultCode
     * @param intent
     */
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if(requestCode == VR_Request && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<String> result = intent.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

            if(wordBANK.contains(result.get(0).toLowerCase()) && UnSpokenList.get(randomNum).contains(result.get(0).toLowerCase())){
                speechInput.setText(result.get(0).toUpperCase());
                matchOrNot.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                matchOrNot.setText("CORRECT!");
                UnSpokenList.remove(result.get(0).toLowerCase());
                SpokenList.add(result.get(0).toLowerCase());
                pass.setClickable(false);
                pass.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                speechBtn.setClickable(false);

                if(UnSpokenList.size() > 3){
                    next.setClickable(true);
                    next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else{
                    last2image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    last2image.setClickable(true);
                }
            }else{
                speechInput.setText("");
                matchOrNot.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                matchOrNot.setText("TRY AGAIN!");
                pass.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pass.setClickable(true);
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

**EDIT: Error Message:**
This error message occurs every time I pressed the last2image button, and gives the crash message:  "unfortunately, pic has stopped running"

```
    08-17 15:58:31.083 13036-13036/com.example.speechtotext E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.speechtotext, PID: 13036
                                                                             java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                 at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4452)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3
                                                                                 at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                                 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                                 at com.example.speechtotext.Main.onlastPair(Main.java:222)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447) 
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
08-17 15:58:33.495 13036-13036/com.example.speechtotext I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 13036 SIG: 9
08-17 15:58:33.966 17345-17345/com.example.speechtotext W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.speechtotext-2/lib/x86
08-17 15:58:34.302 17345-17345/com.example.speechtotext W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.speechtotext-2/lib/x86
08-17 15:58:34.673 17345-17345/com.example.speechtotext W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
08-17 15:58:34.748 17345-17386/com.example.speechtotext D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                                             [ 08-17 15:58:34.759 17345:17345 D/         ]
                                                                             HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaa23f4c0, tid 17345
08-17 15:58:34.828 17345-17386/com.example.speechtotext I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-17 15:58:34.885 17345-17386/com.example.speechtotext W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-17 15:58:34.888 17345-17386/com.example.speechtotext W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaa23e540, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

The function that runs when the button is click is the onlastPair() function,

```
public void onlastPair(View view){
        if(view.getId() == R.id.last2){
            if(!UnSpokenList.get(UnSpokenList.size()).contains("Word Bank:")) {
                resID = res.getIdentifier(UnSpokenList.get(UnSpokenList.size()), "drawable", getApplication().getPackageName());
                image.setImageResource(resID);

                speechBtn.setClickable(true);
                pass.setClickable(false);
                pass.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }else {
                onGameOver();
            }
        }
    }
```

originally the error message directed to the two lines below as part an error:

```
  if(!UnSpokenList.get(UnSpokenList.size()).contains("Word Bank:")) {
                    resID = res.getIdentifier(UnSpokenList.get(UnSpokenList.size()), "drawable", getApplication().getPackageName());
```

so i decided to change the function shown below,

```
    public void onlastPair(View view){
    if(view.getId() == R.id.last2){
        if(!UnSpokenList.get(1).isEmpty()) {
            int max = UnSpokenList.size();

            resID = res.getIdentifier(UnSpokenList.get(max), "drawable", getApplication().getPackageName());
            image.setImageResource(resID);

            speechBtn.setClickable(true);
            pass.setClickable(false);
            pass.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }else {
            onGameOver();
        }
    }
}
```

but it still give me an error now this time it is pointing to the line:

```
        int max = UnSpokenList.size();
```

I am not sure what it wrong, maybe it's my logic but it seem to make sense to me or something im missing. Any ideas will be helpful, Thank you!

Comment: If you get a popup like "unfortunately, pic has stopped", your app has crashed. When this happens, a popup always pops up in logcat. Please share it

Comment: To add: You can't always use this `randomNum = (random.nextInt(UnSpokenList.size()) + 1);`. `nextInt()` will return a number between 0 and max - 1. Because your maximum value is a list, you can get a number that represents the last item in your list. However, you are increasing this value meaning that you probably get an `IndexOutOfBoundException` because a list is 0-based

Comment: Originally i didnt, run the through the emulator, but when i did, i got the error message shown in post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`randomNum = (random.nextInt(UnSpokenList.size()) + 1);` is incorrect

`nextInt(15)` gives # 0-14

if your `UnSpokenList.size()` == 15, that means it has indicies from 0-14

so if you do `random.nextInt(UnSpokenList.size()) + 1)` you are actually rng'ing for numbers, 15+1, which will be from 0-15

**15** will fall outside your indicies of 0-14

to ignore your `UnSpokenList(0)`...

you need to change it to: `random.nextInt(UnSpokenList.size() - 1) + 1`

a size 15-1 will rng 0-13, then +1, will make it 1-14 which is perfect for `UnSpokenList(1)` - `UnSpokenList(14)`

we can test this for `UnSpokenList.size()` = 2

`random.nextInt(2 - 1) + 1` = only-0 + 1 = only-1

**EDIT**

`if(!UnSpokenList.get(1).isEmpty())` are you trying to check if your list has more than 1 item? if so, yours can throw index-error, it should be `if (UnSpokenList.size() > 1)`

then once again, `int max = UnSpokenList.size() ... UnSpokenList.get(max)`  you're giving it an index out of bounds, 0-14 but you get(15), it's not going to work

Comment: fixed, but im still getting the crash

Comment: before and after your `randomNum = ...` put these logs: `Log.d(tag, "size:"+UnSpokenList.size())`, then `Log.d(tag, "rand:"+randomNum)`. this will greatly help you diagnose index errors, and when it crashes, look at these 2 logs.

Comment: I was geting a blank image before, it not the random function now, but it did solve one of my issue. Thank you! do you have any idea of the crash issue i just update in the post?

Comment: `if(!UnSpokenList.get(1).isEmpty()) {` are you trying to check if your list only has more than 1 item? if so, yours can throw index-error, it should be `if (UnSpokenList.size() > 1)`

Comment: then once again, `UnSpokenList.get(max)` where `int max = UnSpokenList.size()` you're giving it an index outside. 0-14 but you get(15), it's not going to work